# Operation timed out after publishing .net core app to iis?

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, publish

We've just built a .NET Core Web Application under VS2019 CE (deployed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine), but are facing some issues when trying to deploy it to IIS.

**(EDIT)** After publishing it to our IIS, recycling the app pool (for good measure), and even restarting the "Default Web Site" under IIS, it just sits there loading until the timeout value eventually gets exceeded, and we get the following:

[image]

This is troublesome, since the IIS page itself isn't giving us much more to go on, and even with stdout logging enabled, it doesn't seem to be writing to any logs (have tried giving both absolute and relative paths, but might be missing something/looking over something still? Obviously the logs would help tremendously).

I've tried creating a application, then using Folder Publish from VS to no avail. I've also tried (the preferred way), publishing it directly to our IIS. Publish profile looking something like this (but, unfortunately, with a very similar result):

```
 WebPublishMethod: MSDeploy
 LastUsedBuildConfiguration: Release
 LastUsedPlatform: Any CPU
 SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish: http://localhost:80/Visualiser
 LaunchSiteAfterPublish: True
 ExcludeAppData: False
 TargetFramework: netcoreapp2.0
 SelfContained: true
 MSDeployServiceURL: localhost
 DeployIISAppPath: Default Web Site/Visualiser
 SkipExtraFilesOnServer: False
 MSDeployPublishMethod: InProc
 EnableMSDeployBackup: False
 RuntimeIdentifier: win-x64
```

The app pool under IIS is set to No Managed Code, and I have also confirmed "Enable 32-bit Applications" is set to False. I have also added `<AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>` under the projects *.csproj file, as it wasn't finding the module otherwise (but I don't feel like that should be too related?).

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT 2:** I have now gotten the stdout logging to work (this by changing which account is used by the IIS App Pool). Initially we got `MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN does not match the expected pairing token` , which was fixed by adding `UseUrls()` in the project. However, after resolving that, all we are getting from the logs are the following, which is only digging us deeper into the rabbit hole:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
  User profile is available. Using 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection- 
Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Visualiser
Now listening on: http://localhost:16120
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
    Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/Visualiser
```

Last but not least, our `Program.cs` setup is currently looking like this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://*:80")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Comment: AnyCPU may be defaulting to 32 bit mode.

Comment: What are the issues themselves? Reveal the details please.

Comment: My bad, I don't see how that's something I missed. Question updated! @LexLi

Comment: @jdweng Tried setting "Enable 32-bit applications" to `True` as I feel like that should allow it to load, if AnyCPU does default to 32bit? Unfortunately didn't change anything, though.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/platform-compiler-option

Comment: Are there any related logs in the Windows Event Viewer in the Application section?

Comment: @AndrewSilver The only relevant entry is on the Information level, suggesting the application started process '9960' and that it is listening on port '9181'.

Comment: There are quite a few unknowns here.This can be permissions issue, or some code in startup, etc. Have you tried running this application with all permissions on local system (like administrator)? If it works, then you can scale down and check again. Note that running with admin permissions is not a solution, this is purely for diagnostics purpose.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar I did have to change the user used by the AppPool in IIS in order for it to start pushing out logs at all, Yes. If that answers your question?

Comment: @Xariez, Did you set Identity of `AppPool` to `LocalSystem`? did you check the security of you folder to have user as `IIS AppPool`? did your `exe`  of project file host with no problem? did you increased load time out and test `<aspNetCore requestTimeout="01:10:00"/>` under `system.webServer`?

Comment: I have a feeling that this is suppose to run "out of process" but trying to run in process. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @Aria Identity is set to the user account which has all permissions. I've been told to not "manually" mess with the permissions for the folder, but I could always give it a shot if you insist? Will check the `exe` now. I haven't tried messing with system.webServer, but if memory serves I did try increasing the timeout value in IIS to no avail, unfortunately.

Comment: @Aria What you said did bear some fruit. Trying to launch the `exe` "manually" from the folder shows "Unable to start Kestrel ... ERROR -4092 EACCES permission denied.". I believe it has *something* to do with our Program.cs. Have updated the original question with it's contents.

Comment: Just to see the change, can you try removing CGI from your IIS? Very small chance but it might give an idea https://serverfault.com/a/519776/531398

Comment: @boyukbas Using the link you provided, only "Common HTTP Features, Health and Diagnostics, Performance, Security" seems to be checked. Application Development is marked as `(Not installed)`. Could it be as simple of a solution as this?

Comment: @Xarlez, did it help?

Comment: @boyukbas The machine is accessed via TeamViewer currently and seems to have gone down, so for the time being I unfortunately have no idea. Trying to get in touch with the owners.

Comment: It would be great for everyone to get a clear picture of the issue. by sharing snapshots of IIS and VS web publish area.

Comment: @Xarlez It's not cool to set a bounty and don't even spend time to reply comments.

Comment: @boyukbas I have been responding to comments so your point is invalid. It's difficult for me to "share snapshots" of anything while the machine everything is happening on is inaccessible, as per my last comment. And apart from that, the only comment lacking a response is the InProcess/OutOfProcess related one, which while I tested, I never got to test properly and thus had no answer for either.

Comment: @boyukbas But don't get me wrong, I agree setting a bounty, then ignoring the question, is not "cool" at all.

Comment: Sorry for my false judgement. I would like to ask a question to clarify it. Did you check "Application Development" features? I believe you did but if you didn't, I believe you should.

Comment: @boyukbas I checked them, which prompted for a computer restart, which is when we for some reason lost access unfortunately (should be configured to prevent this from happening). I will update the question as soon as we gain access again!

Comment: @boyukbas We finally got access to the server again, but unfortunately, checking App. Development, App. Initialization and SSI did not change anything - we are still getting error 502. Trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: However, it certainly makes me think. The Site bindings and Startup.cs (in the VS project) are bound to port 80, but the logs are reporting "Now listening on: http://localhost:28681" - so different ports?